# AutoMapper and mapping one-to-many on Create

Tags: c#, automapper

So my DB has a one-to-many association between a customer and orders.
Mapping the data to show a customer and his orders is no problem. But is there a way to map these when creating a customer?

For example:
"The very basic viewModel just to test the Mapping"

```
public class CVM  
{  
    public string ContactName { get; set; }  //Part of the Customer Table  
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }  //Part of the Orders Table and 
    //would have to be passed into the Orders List of the EF-Customer-Object  
}
```

So the create view just has 2 inputs for Name and Date. 
"The very basic controller just to test the Mapping ;)"

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Create(CVM model)  
{  
    Mapper.CreateMap<CVM, Customer>();  
    Customer customer = Mapper.Map<CVM, Customer>(model);  
    return View();  
}
```

So ContactName gets mapped properly. The Problem is the OrderDate. AutoMapper would have to create an Order instance, set the value of OrderDate and pass it to the OrdersCollection of the Customer object. Is AutoMapper able to do this or am I totally wrong?

Hope you understand my explanation and someone has an Answer to me.

Thanks Folks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about it the wrong way. What you should be doing is to instantiate a `Customer` instance and then map it s properties using AutoMapper.

Thus, your code would look like:

```
[HttpPost]  
public ActionResult Create(CVM model)  
{  
    Mapper.CreateMap<CVM, Customer>();
    Customer customer = /* Construct or get a Customer instance, eg from DB. */
    Mapper.Map<CVM, Customer>(model, customer);  
    return View();  
}
```

BTW, you should make sure to have `Mapper.CreateMap<CVM, Customer>()` directives only during application startup, otherwise you are needlessly performing this (possibly costly) step on every request.

#### Edit

It seems I read the original question wrong. If the aim is to create a Customer with associated objects, then Automapper can help you in a few different ways (I am going forward with the Person/PhoneNumber example you gave in the comments).

Given that your Entities and View Models are:

```
public Person {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string List<PhoneNumber> Numbers { get; set; }
}

public PersonVM {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string IList<PhoneNumberVM> Numbers { get; set; }
}

public PhoneNumber {
  public int Type { get; set; }
  public string Number { get; set; }
}

public PhoneNumberVM {
  public int Type { get; set; }
  public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

then you have a few alternatives:

1. You can try to write a custom Mapping rule so that each `PhoneNumberVM` instance is mapped to a `PhoneNumber` instance, or
2. You can add a `Mapper.CreateMap<PhoneNumberVM, PhoneNumber>()` and just call `Mapper.Map<PersonVM, Person>(model)` to have your model mapped to your entity.

Of course, you would have to make sure that your model gets constructed properly, but that is not very hard as long as you use the same model to generate your HTML form.

Comment: Thanks but I think that will not help me. What I am trying to do is actually creating a customer and an order at the same time. Think about a person with a name and a various number of phone numbers (represented by a list in the person entity). I would like to create a createView containing a field for name and lets say 3 fields for different phone number (private,business,mobile). AutoMapper should now map the numbers to phone number entities and add them to the phone number list of the person entity. I hope I made it clear and not more difficult ^^

Comment: I see, I guess I didn't completely understand the question as asked. I had to do something similar myself at one point. I think the trick is to properly name your properties on the ViewModel. Thus your `CVM` would have to have a property `IList<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers`, and then AutoMapper would be able to map those just fine. You could also create a view model for the `PhoneNumber` objects like `PhoneNumberVM` and map using that as well.

Comment: I'm not really getting it. The IList<PhoneNumber> property in my CustomerViewModel would not help me. There would not be a possibility to set a value for this property. And how should a PhoneNumberViewModel help me? For me it looks like AutoMapper isn't able to handle this. Maybe you could give me an example. Lets take my last example with the phone number. The EntityObjects should look like this: Person: Name | PhoneNumbers (List of type PhoneNumber) and PhoneNumer: Type | Number. So my ViewModel would be ContactViewModel: Name | Type | Number. ----->

Comment: ----------> In my view I have inputs for a Name, a Type and a Number. This gets passed to the controllers createAction. How should the mapping look like?

Comment: Thanks again ^^ So lets say we make a CreateView for a Person that inherits the PersonVM. There is now way to enter a phone number because the viewModel has a list and not a single property for numbers. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea. Of course, you need to somehow dynamically create new input boxes (or the like) to hold the multiple phone numbers that will be created, so that when the form is posted, they are mapped to the list elements. I don't exactly remember the format for those but I remember Phil Haack had a blog post about ModelBinding to sequences, way back in the day.

Comment: I LOVE YOU! Found the blog post and that was the missing part. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great; glad to be of service. Best of luck on your endeavor.